# SynchronizationContext thread get hang and it gets triggered after 5 hours

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, synchronization

Actually i am facing an issue in using SynchronizationContext triggering get delayed by 5 hours.

we are initialize the SynchronizationContext in main form ie., when the application is launched

```
public static System.Threading.SynchronizationContext MainUISynchronizationContext { get; set; }

public HiddenForm()
{

  MainUISynchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

}
```

and by using SynchronizationContext i am trying to launch the new form but it is triggering after 5 hour in some cases

```
private void ShowFormAsync(ProHanceForm form)
{
    try
    {
        if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug("Current synchronization thread is : " + ((HiddenForm.MainUISynchronizationContext == null) ? "null" : HiddenForm.MainUISynchronizationContext.ToString()));

        HiddenForm.MainUISynchronizationContext.Post(_ => { dummyForm.Show(); }, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("An exception occurred while showing the form through Synchronization Context.", ex);

    }
}
```

how can we handle this kind of cases where form is triggered after 5 hours.

Comment: The Post delegate can only execute if the main thread is not busy.  You will have to debug this.  Debug > Break All, then Debug > Windows > Threads and find out what the main thread is doing that it should not be doing.

Comment: In this case if the thread is busy how can we make the thread free and perform my action.